# Why is the maximum number not showing in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to find both the maximum and the minimum number from a prompt that is given to the user. For some reason only Math.min seems to be working and not the Math.max. Why is this?

```js
var userNum = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter five numbers separated by commas"), 10);

window.console.log("The lowest number is: " + Math.min(userNum));

window.console.log("The highest number is: " + Math.max(userNum));
//HIGHEST DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK
```

Comment: I tried using alerts instead, but the browser showed me the first number entered for both "lowest number" and "highest number."

Answer (score 3):

You are parsing a string which contains a sequence of commas separated numbers, but parseInt doesn't return what you would like, instead it returns just the first number in that sequence.

The result you supposedly wanted to achieve:

```js
var userNum = prompt("Enter five numbers separated by commas").split(',')
// prompt returns a string, you can make an array splitting by commas
// https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

window.console.log("The lowest number is: " + Math.min( ...userNum ));
// spread the array into min() and max() with ... operator
// https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754

window.console.log("The highest number is: " + Math.max( ...userNum ));
```

Comment: The numbers are returning as NaN. What else am I missing?

Comment: @Aj96 are you typing them separated by commas? Because this works for me if I type in `2, 100` or `1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: The above code works in brackets even though it gives an error signal (for the ...). I've never seen the ... that is used before passing in the value of userNum. When I do not have the ... in my code, it comes up as NaN. What does ... mean in JS?

Comment: @Aj96 `...` is the [spread operator](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754)